# How does one keep others down voting or deleting answers because they do fast answers to hard problem or answers at all to impossible problems>?

Tags: discussion

As I said in [Fitting an exponential system](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/283080/fitting-an-exponential-system): "Sometimes, a negative result (i.e., can not be fast or done at all) [needs to given] as the problem is constructed." (I editted my own sentence.)

These problems resemble:

1. Fast method is needed for factoring a positive integer that Mathematica's PrimeQ test is composite. Here is an example integer:

```
composite = 196224608383212646131439112319062531\
673464636863429917932749195368878401764748198586\
422362033096032823583097942405346999204902420147\
735275463409187601663781622781284814546080898702\
653502638021919110209657858084760294191954280513\
805370921206125053294065587018659051189057976439\
680054704159322453822755537793158520225992385741\
879626577017028343052949935693055356892534134395\
008399749506705632472808052546145065604937559076\
251352535630224078146589113080417626476838375722\
960197501129299584442929835934403886175427699514\
466875279003197591217770612882907037116398062458\
414612783249106211820941186912416332148001;
```

2. I need a solution in positive integers of the expression $x^p+y^p==z^p" where $p$ is a prime greater than 2.

In the case of first problem, it can be done; but, it will be slow. I know the primes in this case. In the case of the second problem, it can not be done at all. Please, see "[350 Years Later, Fermat's Last Theorem Finally Proved](https://beta.nsf.gov/news/350-years-later-fermats-last-theorem-finally)".

At a major national-level research laboratory, I provided computer and programming support for several of the larger experiments at the laboratory. Often scientists would come for assistance and very occasionally, I had to inform the scientist that the problem fell into one of the cases above. Some of those departed unhappy because they did not get a *magic* answer (Arthur C. Clarke,[Clarke's Third Law on UFO's](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.159.3812.255.c), 19 Jan 1968, Vol 159, Issue 3812, p. 255).

I have now encountered a number of members that seem to feel that if an answer does not supply a fast solution with results, then the answer needs to be down voted or deleted, which they proceed to do. How does one stop such users or mediate their damage?

Comment: I have downvoted some of your answers in the past weeks (but also upvoted several others!), but I almost always provide at least a short comment of why I decided on a down vote, and others usually do the same. If you get an unexpected downvote, you can ask in the comment for an explanation. As for the concrete example: If you hover with your mouse over a downvote arrow symbol, it says _This answer is not useful._ If you read the guide on [_How do I write a good answer?_](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), it says:

Comment: _What is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or at least a viable alternative. Your answer can say “don’t do that,” but it should also say “try this instead.”_ First, your answer had some factual inaccuracies (data being 64 GB in size). Second, your answer really was not an _answer_, it was a _comment_. It did not solve the OP's problem, it gave no alternative, no _real_ explanation or reasoning on why you think the problem is impossible to solve (comparing his minimization problem to Fermat's theorem is quite a false equivalence in my opinion), ...

Comment: ... and it also contained a question for some clarification (which belongs, again, in the comments). Third, your many years of experience are surely much appreciated and can be of great use in providing answers on this site – but this belongs to your profile, not in an answer. And lastly, I don't really understand the title of this question – What is wrong with fast answers to hard problems? Isn't it amazing (and one of the main purposes of this site) that some people can quickly find an answer to someone's problem? :)

Comment: To summarize: If you have some _comments_ about the question, need clarification, or want to express a concern about the existence of viable solution, post them as _comments_. When you come up with an _answer_ that _solves the problem_, post is as an answer, and you will surely get – at least for a good answer – many upvotes (downvotes are actually quite rare on this site, compared to some other StackExchange sites, believe me).

Comment: @Domen You do not read carefully. I never said that the input data was on the order of 64 GB. The $y$ expressions in Sam Wolfe's example, if fully expanded, for 2000 data points, run on the order of 64 GB. That is a measurement using **ByteCount**.

Comment: @Domen So far, I have seen only one down vote on an answer. I expanded the answer to cover that down vote.

Comment: Both sam wolfe and I understood it the same way, so it might not be our reading, but your writing which is not careful.

Comment: @Domen Some problem can not be solved no manner how much some one wants that answer: "I need a solution in positive integers to x^3+y^3==z^3", for example.

Comment: @Domen Some problems are just difficult, like the general case of inversion of very large matrices, which is at least $O(n^2 \log{n}}$. The security of the RSA PKI encryption system is based on how hard it is to factor a large composite integer which is the product of only very large primes.

Comment: @Domen Telling someone that "it can not be done" is an answer.

Comment: @Domen If fast answers are availlable, then fine, supplying those answers is good. A questioner demanding an answer that meets needed when it is not available is unreasonable on the questioner's part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How does one stop such users or mediate their damage?

One does not. It is your interpretation that damage is being done, but regardless, even if damage was being done, you cannot stop it. This is a community of users, each member of which gains certain permissions by attaining certain levels of reputation. You can use your reputation-based permissions to try to do what you think best. Your ideas of what is best will compete against the ideas of the rest of the community. It's a wisdom-of-the-crowd situation, not one governed by strict enforcement of explicitly codified laws.